# How do I Transform / Pivot in Access SQL but without aggregating?

Tags: sql, ms-access, pivot, transform

Firstly, thank you to anyone that can help, I hope this is a simple question for those in the know.

I have Data which is of the form:

```
LeaseID | ChargeID
1 | 1
1 | 2
2 | 3
3 | 4
3 | 5
3 | 6
```

i.e. LeaseID 1 has 2 ChargeIDs

How can I query this in Access SQL so that the data will be reflected as

```
LeaseID | ChargeID | ChargeID | ChargeID
1 | 1 | 2
2 | 3
3 | 4 | 5 | 6
```

I know I am limited to 255 columns but this is not a problem as there will never be 255 but the number of columns should increase with the maximum number of ChargeIDs on a given lease.

I believe it is something to do with Transform / Pivot but have been unable to get it working. I keep getting the "too many crosstabs error"

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a two-step process involving a staging table:

**Make-Table Query** *(using correlated subquery with slow performance on very large tables)*

```
SELECT t.LeaseID, t.ChargeID, 'ChargeID' & (SELECT count(*) FROM LeaseCharge sub
                                            WHERE sub.LeaseID = t.LeaseID 
                                            AND   sub.ChargeID <= t.ChargeID) As Rank
INTO myStagingTable
FROM myTable t;
```

**Cross-Tab Query**

```
TRANSFORM MAX(s.ChargeID) As MaxChargeID
SELECT  s.LeaseID
FROM myStagingTable s
GROUP BY s.LeaseID
PIVOT s.[Rank]

-- LeaseID  ChargeID1   ChargeID2   ChargeID3
--       1          1           2   
--       2          3       
--       3          4           5           6
```

Comment: This is great, thank you so much!

What if I needed to complicate things where by the column headers became something like:

LeaseID  ChargeID1  ChargeName1  ChargeAmount1  ChargeID2  ChargeName2  ChargeAmount2.....

and this sequence repeated based on the count(*) part of the Make-Table Query?

Comment: I suppose this could be done by running a query on ID like you have done, then running another on Name, and then joining based on LeaseID?

or might there be a better way?

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Correct. Join multiple crosstabs together for such an output. But do remember the limit of 255 columns.